# C# - List - remove all elements but NOT the first four

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of elements, however if the number of list elements is greater than 4 I want to remove all elements but leave the first 4 only in the list.

Example:

List<> - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

The new list should be - 1,2,3,4

I am looking at using List.RemoveAll() but not sure what to put in the parentheses

Looking forward to some help ....

Steven

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Why not use [`List.RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5):

```
if (list.Count > 4)
{
    list.RemoveRange(4, list.Count - 4);
}
```

(That's assuming you *want* to mutate the existing list. If you're happy creating a new sequence, I'd definitely use `list.Take(4)` as per Adam's suggestion, with or without the `ToList` call. These days I tend to build queries rather than mutating existing collections.)

Comment: +1 for answering the the question directly, but I agree with your query sentiment.  I find a list/array/new collection is required over an enumerable in fewer and fewer instances these days.

Comment: @jon so to clarify this method will remove the elements from the list leaving only the first four. If so this is perfect, thanks :)

Comment: @swade1987: Yes, that's exactly what it will do. See the linked documentation for more details.

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, you could create a new list with items from the old:

```
var firstFour = myList.Take(4).ToList();
```

This creates a *new* list, however, so is **not** the same as removing from the original list.

Or if all you need to do is *iterate* them, simply `Take` without `ToList` inside a `foreach`:

```
foreach (var item in myList.Take(4))
```

You then get deferred execution and are not spending memory on creating lists.

Just as a side note, with linq and linq extensions I find the code declares your *intent* more explicitly: `list.Take(4)` reads a lot easier than `list.RemoveRange(4, list.Count - 4);` at a glance. Intent in code is very important for maintenance and working in teams.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) of LINQ.

```
myList = myList.Take(4).ToList()
```

This takes first 4 items of your list and assigns a new list in place of your old list.

No need to check length as in other answers because **"Take enumerates source and yields elements until count elements have been yielded or source contains no more elements."** courtesy [Adam Houldsworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358221/adam-houldsworth)

Comment: Well, it assigns it to a *new* list in place of the old one - which will be flagged for GC assuming this was the only reference to it. It does nothing to the same list aside from iterating the first 4 items of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  List<string> lstTest = new List<string>();
            lstTest.Add("test1");
            lstTest.Add("test2");
            lstTest.Add("test3");
            lstTest.Add("test4");
            lstTest.Add("test5");
            lstTest.Add("test6");           

            lstTest.RemoveRange(4, lstTest.Count - 4);

            foreach (string item in lstTest)
            {
                Console.Write(item);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```