# remove all element except from given index number

Tags: c#, linq

I have following list and how can I remove with linq all elements from given index number:

```
    List<string> a = new List<string>();
        a.Add("number1");
        a.Add("number2");
        a.Add("number3");
```

How can I remove all element just except element which is index number =2 using linq.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - List - remove all elements but NOT the first four](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531284/c-sharp-list-remove-all-elements-but-not-the-first-four)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LINQ isn't about *removing* things - it's about *querying*.

You can call [`RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx) to remove a range of items from a list though. So:

```
a.RemoveRange(0, 2);
```

will leave just "number3".

Or you could create a new list as per dasblinkenlight's answer. If you can tell us more about what you're trying to achieve and why you think LINQ is the solution, we may be able to help you more.

EDIT: Okay, now we have clearer requirements, you *can* use LINQ:

```
var newList = a.Where((value, index) => index != 2)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: well sablinkenlights answer is what i look for, i was looking for easy way for that. i was thinking to select elements which is not equal given index number. for example: I dont want to select the element which is index number 2, i want to select elements index number 1 and 3.but you are right linq is not about removing.

Comment: @MichaelRiva: So you're *not* actually trying to remove elements from a list? You're looking to create a new list? It's important to be clear about these things. And it sounds like you're trying to filter out element 2, not filtering out everything *but* element 2? You're being *very* unclear...

Comment: @MichaelRiva: So what do you *actually want*? We don't know whether we've answered you yet.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok I have List<T> a; and i want to send that list to a new list except a[2]

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have list of indices you want to keep, you can use `Where` with `index` to filter:

```
 var indexList = new[] {2};
 var result = a.Where((s, index) => indexList.Contains(index));
```

Comment: `var result = a.Where((s, index) => index==2);` is even simpler, but you need to add a call of `ToList()` after either one.

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent operation to "remove everything but X" is "keep X". The simplest way to do it is constructing a new list with a single element at index `2`, like this:

```
a = new List<string>{a[2]};
```

Answer (score 2):

Although @dasblinkenlight's answer is the better option, here is the linq (or at least one iteration)

```
a.Where((item,index) => b1 == 2);
```

or to return a single string objects rather than an IEnumberable

```
a.Where((a1,b1) => b1 == 2).First();
```