# Remove all but the first item in a list

Tags: c#, .net, list

let us consider a list as below

list contains values as `a,b,c,d`....

i need a query to just remove all the values in the list other than that "a".

Comment: Why not just create a new list that contains a?

Comment: you need query in what? sql?

Comment: Use First() is not working for you?

Comment: @DanielKelley is it having any other way than that?

Comment: list.RemoveRange(index, count); is an option, if you have sorted your list already. Or list.RemoveAll() with appropriate predicate can work for you.

Comment: @ryadavilli: Why is it important that the list is sorted? I assume that `a` is just an example, he wants to remove **all but the first**.

Comment: @TimSchmelter What you say is true. The OP was not clear on that part though. On the face value of it, it does not matter if the list is sorted or not and remove range as in your answer fits the bill perfectly. However, I was not sure of making an assumption that "a" is the first and he wants to retain only the first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - List - remove all elements but NOT the first four](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531284/c-sharp-list-remove-all-elements-but-not-the-first-four)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[`List.RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y33yd2b5.aspx) is what you're looking for:

```
if(list.Count > 1)
    list.RemoveRange(1, list.Count - 1);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/kaXgqZ)

Comment: what if its not the first element in the list?

Comment: this is late but think it should be list.count not list.count-1

Comment: @mj1261829: Why? OP wanted to remove all items but the first. Since the second argument in [`List<T>.RemoveRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removerange?view=net-5.0) is the count and we start with the second item, it must be `list.Count - 1`, otherwise we get an `ArgumentException`.

Answer (score 18):

```
List<T> elements = ....

elements.RemoveAll(x => x != a)
```

**UPD**

for removing other than first you need to use RemoveRange as Tim Schmelter sayed.

or make new list with first element. 
elements.First()

Comment: that a is unknow means what shall i do it?

Comment: What do you mean "a is unknown" ? YOu can hold it in a variable and pass that to this query.

Comment: if a is unknown now and you need to "remove all the values in the list other that "a"". You need get a somewhere

Comment: Look at the title, he wants to remove all but the first, not all but `a`.

Comment: And if this is your hometask, you need to write yours RemoveAll with loops and if conditions