# C# remove datatable duplicates based on field and condition

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to remove duplicates from a datatable based on a specific field and a condition

Like if I have the following records:

name: Ali

appointment_type: dental

appointment_date: 8/5/2017 08:00:00

name: ali

appointment_type: dental

appointment_date: 8/5/2017 16:00:00

from the above example, the patient Ali has two appointments, I want to remove the later appointment(s) (which is on 8/5/2017 16:00:00)

in other words,
remove all appointment of patient "Ali" and keep the earliest one only

is it possible to do it in LINQ?

Comment: First filter them in a Where and then apply RemoveRange as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746783/remove-all-but-the-first-item-in-a-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to `GroupBy` the items and then `OrderBy` each group based on `AppointmentDate`, take only the `First` (earliest) from each group. The result will be the earliest appointment only:

```
List<Patient> patients = new List<Patient>(); //change this with your actual list/IEnumerable

IEnumerable<Patient> earliestAppointmentRecorded = patients.GroupBy(x => x.Name.ToLower().Trim())
   .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.AppointmentDate).First());
```

Assuming the `class` is like below:

```
public class Patient {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string AppointmentType { get; set; }
  public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }

};
```

And, say, you want to replace the earlier records with the ones of the `earliestAppointmentRecorded`, you could simply do:

```
patients = earliestAppointmentRecorded.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("appointment_type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("appointment_date", typeof(DateTime));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Ali", "dental", DateTime.Parse("8/5/2017 08:00:00")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Ali", "dental", DateTime.Parse("8/5/2017 16:00:00")});

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new { name = x.Field<string>("name"), type = x.Field<string>("appointment_type") }).ToList();

            dt = groups.Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Field<DateTime>("appointment_date")).LastOrDefault()).CopyToDataTable();

        }
```